# Can HDP (Hierarchical Dirichilet Process) detect the number of topics from the data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, gensim, topic-modeling, unsupervised-learning

I am using HDP (Hierarchical Dirichilet Process) package from gensim topic modelling software. Gensim HDP implementation expects user to provide number of topics (T) in advance.

`hdpmodel.HdpModel(self, corpus, id2word,T=150)`

The documentation defines T as top level truncation level.

Can HDP determine number of topics on its own?
Is there an implementation of HDP which can detect number of topics? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a separate site for software recommendations, you can try that. On SO off-site recommendations are off topic.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have edited this question and posted a separate question on software recommendation page as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the *stick-breaking prior*.

Some people have reported good results. Others said it did not work for them at all.

Guess you will have to *implement* this yourself and see if it works.